# Daily rate of return based on limited values - pandas

Tags: python

I wanted to calculate daily log rate of return for Optionvalue but only for first 252days in the data. I'm getting KeyError: 'log return'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

EUR = pd.read_csv('C:eurpln_d.csv', sep = ",", parse_dates=['Date'])
USD = pd.read_csv('C:usdpln_d.csv', sep = ",", parse_dates=['Date'])


w_1 = 0.5
w_2 = 1-w_1
EUR.merge(USD, on="Date")
EUR["Optionvalue"] = EUR["Close"]*w_1 + EUR["Close"]*w_2
```

So what i would like to have is log return but only on first 252days (which is to say I need to take only 252 first occurences, in this dailylogreturn calculation): log(yt)−log(yt−1). I've tried to use below.

```
EUR['log return'].iloc[0:252]= np.log(EUR["Optionvalue"]) - np.log(EUR["Optionvalue"].iloc[0])
```

1. Is my "np.log(EUR["Optionvalue"].iloc[0]" correctly taking previous value when calculating log return?
2. How can I limit data so I can calculate daily log return based only on first 252 dates? Above              `.iloc[0:252]` seems to not work..Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Small example

- `iloc[0]` will just give you the first row of something, not the previous value. You can use `shift(1)` (shown below) to get the previous value.
- When taking the previous value, the first item will be NA or NaN since there is no previous value of the first value. You can use `fillna` to provide an "artificial" value (1 in the below example)

  - Note that the first value in the last column is therefore artificial. Remove the `fillna` to keep this value `NaN`.
- You should do `iloc` on an existing column. You can initialize a new column with a fixed value (e.g. -1 as in below)
- You can remove the `prev` column below and use its value directly in the last assignment, if desired.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

d = {'date': [datetime(2020, 5, d) for d in range(1, 30)],
     'current': [x for x in range(1, 30)]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['prev'] = df.shift(1).fillna(1)['current']
df['logdiff'] = -1
df['logdiff'].iloc[0:20] = np.log(df['current']) - np.log(df['prev'])

print(df)
```

```
         date  current  prev   logdiff
0  2020-05-01        1   1.0  0.000000
1  2020-05-02        2   1.0  0.693147
2  2020-05-03        3   2.0  0.405465
3  2020-05-04        4   3.0  0.287682
4  2020-05-05        5   4.0  0.223144
5  2020-05-06        6   5.0  0.182322
6  2020-05-07        7   6.0  0.154151
7  2020-05-08        8   7.0  0.133531
8  2020-05-09        9   8.0  0.117783
9  2020-05-10       10   9.0  0.105361
10 2020-05-11       11  10.0  0.095310
11 2020-05-12       12  11.0  0.087011
12 2020-05-13       13  12.0  0.080043
13 2020-05-14       14  13.0  0.074108
14 2020-05-15       15  14.0  0.068993
15 2020-05-16       16  15.0  0.064539
16 2020-05-17       17  16.0  0.060625
17 2020-05-18       18  17.0  0.057158
18 2020-05-19       19  18.0  0.054067
19 2020-05-20       20  19.0  0.051293
20 2020-05-21       21  20.0 -1.000000
21 2020-05-22       22  21.0 -1.000000
22 2020-05-23       23  22.0 -1.000000
23 2020-05-24       24  23.0 -1.000000
24 2020-05-25       25  24.0 -1.000000
25 2020-05-26       26  25.0 -1.000000
26 2020-05-27       27  26.0 -1.000000
27 2020-05-28       28  27.0 -1.000000
28 2020-05-29       29  28.0 -1.000000
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm very new to python so I have zero experience. Do you know how can I do that for entire year and not specified month? ie. entire 2020?

Comment: From datetime, import timedelta (not just datetime). Then for the second range above, add a `timedelta(days=x)` to a starting date and extend the range to 365 days.